# rails 3- adding page specific javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a JavaScript on one view page, how can i do that?
I'm using rails 4 in my application.

I have tried this but it is not working, in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('user_button').click(function() {
        $('some_div').show();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Rails 3 or 4? Why are you trying to put this in your view? Use assets/javascripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this always works, make use of yield.

in application.html.erb, add:

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

then in your view page where you want to add javascript:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      //script here
      }
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```